# How to send a PGP encrypted message to the IOTA tangle?

Tags: iota-network, iota-recovery

I have done the phase 1 of the IOTA claim process.

Now I am blocked with how to start the phase 2: 
it is mentioned to do this:  As part of this process, you’ll publish a PGP encrypted message containing your old seed to the tangle which we’ll then use to verify & send you your tokens.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the screens on the wallet. You don't have to do the PGP yourself, the wallet will (in the background) send the PGP encrypted message to <strike>a webserver operated by the IOTA foundation</strike> [the tangle](https://github.com/iotaledger/wallet/blob/810ea524f6b957a017fa4ba085041d05bf5358d4/ui/js/ui.recover.js#L391-L392).

The only thing you have to be aware of: After doing the reclaim, the IOTA foundation will have your old seed in plaintext. So if you don't trust them, make sure there are no other funds than the ones to reclaim on that seed. And never use any addresses generated by that seed again.